# How to create a program where a user can check if an item is on the menu?

Tags: python, string, boolean

I want to create a program where a user can check if an item is on the menu.

My code is:

```
menu = "salad, pasta, sandwich, pizza, drinks, dessert"
menu_ask = (input())
print('menu_ask = ', 'menu_ask' in menu)
```

and my output is:

```
pasta
menu_ask =  False
```

However, the output needs to be True, because pasta is in the menu. Why does the code return a False?

Thank you.

Comment: Because you used the literal string `'menu_ask'`... Just put `menu_ask in menu`

Comment: _Why does the code return a False?_ `'menu_ask'` is not in `menu`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `'` from around `menu_ask`

```
menu = "salad, pasta, sandwich, pizza, drinks, dessert"
menu_ask = (input())
print('menu_ask = ', menu_ask in menu)
```

That variable holds your input - you can check if that is part of the menu directly.